# Different KML File Formats From Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'm creating KML files from Google Earth Polygons. However, the created KML files will appear in two different formats. One type, when appearing in Google Earth, will appear as a link. Another will appear as plain text. 
The KML that appears as a link has format like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Placemark>
    <name>GHG</name>
    <ExtendedData>
        <Data name="stroke">
            <value>#555555</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="stroke-width">
            <value>2</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="stroke-opacity">
            <value>1</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="fill">
            <value>#555555</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="fill-opacity">
            <value>0.5</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="Code">
            <value>GHG</value>
        </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    35.54397940635681,33.17158011534832,0 35.54336249828339,33.16975707112739,0 35.54345905780792,33.16957296849484,0 35.54412424564362,33.17153521323674,0 35.54397940635681,33.17158011534832,0 
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

The kml format of the plot that appears in plain text looks something like:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>BFB.kml</name>
    <StyleMap id="msn_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#sn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#sh_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="sn_ylw-pushpin">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>99ffffff</color>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="sh_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.2</scale>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>99ffffff</color>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>BFB</name>
        <visibility>0</visibility>
        <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        35.42654700219181,32.70002475720476,0 35.43086711604241,32.70023107874993,0 35.43106772797857,32.7007191672116,0 35.42656173211241,32.70057776992705,0 35.42654700219181,32.70002475720476,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I need to parse these kml files and it is a much easier task when the format is standardized. I'd much prefer the first (GHG) format.

Comment: To clarify - when you say the first one appears as a link, this is when a placemark has a description or ExtendedData and upon clicking displays a description balloon. How are you creating the KML - from Google Earth or a custom application?

Comment: You might want to use an existing XML parser to make things easier. You'll still have to deal w/ two formats, but it should be less tedious.